# Check if user enter sixteen correct unique words

Tags: python, list

I need help in coding this situation:

I need to get words from user input loop until I get 16 unique words to put in a list. I also need to print "duplicates" every time the word inputted by the user is already a duplicate then keep asking until I get 16 unique words.

I don't need to print the unique list afterwards, as I will use them for the next part of my codes , we're also not allowed to use set()

Here's what i've tried by far:

```
mylist = []
def func():
while True:
    words = input()
    mylist.append(words)
    if len(mylist) == 16:
        break
```

Comment: Can you add your approach or any code with the question?

Comment: Just as with ```set```, the ```list``` supports the ```in``` operator. ```if newword in wordlist: print("dup")```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```py
words = [] # creates the list for the unique words
while len(words) != 16: # runs until the length of the list of unique words is equal 16
    new_word = input("Add a new word: ") # asks the user for a new word and stores the input in a variable
    if new_word not in words: # checks if the inputted word is not in the unique words list already
        words.append(new_word) # if it is not, the word gets appended to the list of unique words
    else:
        print("dups") # otherwise "dups" gets printed
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a function

2.Input from user will be taken only if length of duplicates is less than sixteen

3.We check if word is in duplicates words, if it's tell user its a duplicate to
enter another

4.else we add that to list

```
duplicate_words = []
while len(duplicate_words) < 16:
    word = input("Enter a unique word: ")
    if word in duplicate_words:
        print("Duplicate word , enter another word")
    else:
        print("Word is correct!")
        duplicate_words.append(user)
    if len(duplicate_words) == 16:
        print("Sixteen words correct,Good Bye!")
        break
```